# Using seed in PRNG

Tags: java, random, cryptography

In Java, i am generating pseudo random numbers using "SHA1PNRG". I don't know the internal working of this number generation. What seed value will be best for secure number generation? Should i use smaller number as seed or larger value as seed? Please be kind to give proper guidance.

My code:

```
SecureRandom sr= SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
sr.setSeed(seed);
```

I am using `sr.nextInt(int)` for getting next value and `seed` is a long data type variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NIST SP800-90A](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-90A/SP800-90A.pdf) recommends a seed length of 440 bits (i.e. 55 bytes) when using a Hash_DRBG (Deterministic Random Bit Generator) based on SHA-1. (The algorithm is also depicted there).

But it is not only about the length of the seed, but also its entropy ("randomness"). If you initialize a DRBG with a 440-bit string of zeros, it will be a bad choice despite of its length.

The purpose of seeding is configuring the initial state of the generator, so that an attacker will not be able to predict the sequence of random numbers. Remember that all the process is deterministic, then once anyone knows the state of the generator, he will be able to reproduce the random sequence from that point on.

You may calculate the seed by using the method `SecureRandom.generateSeed`, which relies on the entropy source provided by the current OS (for instance, the [SeedGenerator of OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/2d585507a41b/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/SeedGenerator.java) uses /dev/random on Linux and MS CryptoAPI on Windows).

```
 SecureRandom sr= SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");     
 byte seed[] = random.generateSeed(55);
 sr.setSeed(seed);
```

Comment: Thank you Javier. If i use the seed of data type long rather than using as of type byte, will it compromise the security in anyway?

Comment: Yes. First, because `long` is only 64 bits, then your seed is too short. Second, because `nextLong()` returns a pseudo random number based on the current state of the generator (as opposed to a value from an entropy source). If you use `nextLong` as the source of your seed you are feeding almost no entropy because you are trying to "improve" the generator with itself.

Comment: I thought both usage will results the same. Thanks for correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter *what* number you use for the seed.  What's important is that you use a *different* number for the seed each time you start the program.

A PRNG, or pseudo-random number generator, works by performing a calculation on the seed.  It uses the output of that calculation as the seed for the next random number, and so on.  (That's a simplification, but it gives you the right idea.)  So the PRNG will produce the same sequence of numbers if you use the same seed.

Typical seeds are derived from the system time, or from a user's keypresses or mouse movements, or some other value that's likely to be different each time the program runs.

Comment: Thank you Adam Liss. Got idea now.

Comment: "system time" -- no, this should never be used as a seed.

Answer (score 0):

Maximin, if you're concerned about people not being able to guess the seed (and thus predict the outputs from your PRNG), you should use an actually random seed. Using the time that the program is run, for example, is not secure.

You shouldn't bypass the internal seeding mechanism by directly calling `setSeed`. If `java.security.SecureRandom.setSeed(long)` or `java.security.SecureRandom.setSeed(byte[])` is called before a call to `java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(byte[])`, then the internal seeding mechanism is bypassed, and only the provided seed is used to generate random numbers.

See Amit Thesi's useful blog post on this topic from a few years ago at http://www.cigital.com/justice-league-blog/2009/08/14/proper-use-of-javas-securerandom/